# Java generic class constructor invocation

Tags: java, generics, constructor

I have following code:

```
public class A {}

public class B extends A {}

public class C <T extends A> {

  private final T data;

  public C(final T data) {
    this.data = data;
  }
}

public class D<T extends B> extends C<T> {

  public D(T data) {
    super(data);
  }

  public D() {
    this(new B());
  }

  public static D<B> create() {
    return new D(new B());
  }
}
```

There is a compile error in the class D:

```
error: no suitable constructor found for D(B)
    this(new B());
constructor D.D() is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor D.D(T) is not applicable
  (actual argument B cannot be converted to T by method invocation conversion)
where T is a type-variable:
T extends B declared in class D
```

What is confusing me is the fact, that the static method D.create() that does basically the same is compiled without any errors. Can anyone explain this error? And the difference between D() and D.create()?

Comment: You are going to confuse everyone by mixing one-letter class names with generics which by convention use a single letter for the type.

Answer (score 4):

The error is there because for class `D` it is not known that the type will be `B`, only that the generic type will *extend* `B` - you have assumed it's going to be `B` because there are no other classes (yet) in your class hierarchy (a fact that the compiler must consider may change in the future).

---

Note that in the factory method you are instantiating the *raw* type for `D` (one without a generic parameter). Instead, provide a type:

You should change:

```
public static D<B> create() {
    return new D(new B());
}
```

to:

```
public static D<B> create() {
    return new D<B>(new B()); // Note: Added generic parameter <B>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because generic type `T` of class `D` is not bound

This will work

```
public class E extends D<B> {

    public E() {
        super(new B()); // call to D's constructor public D(T data)
    }
}
```

normally you would call the constructor of `D` in this way:

```
new D<B>(new B());
```

but you **CAN NOT** do this

```
public D() {
    this<B>(new B());
}
```

Another example.

Change the code a little bit and you will see the problem.

```
class BBB extends B {
}

class C<T extends A> {

    protected final T data;

    public C(final T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

class D<T extends B> extends C<T> {

    public D() {
        this(new B());
    }

    public T getData(){
        return data;
    }
}

D<BBB> dOfBBB = new D<BBB>();
BBB data = dOfBBB.getData(); // So if this(new B()) would work 
                              // how can the data then be returned?
                              // Because BBB is returned but it would be 
                              // initialized with only a B instance
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Does it mean that in case I want to keep the class D generic (to be able to extend it later the same way as C -> D) I can use only D.create() - I mean there is no way to rewrite D() error free?

Comment: @Petr yes, in your case I would then follow the answer of Bohemian.